# setting a ckeditor instance value using jquery

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I have the following script in newedit.js file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("[id^=save]").click(function() {
        $("#scholarship-short_desc").val("test");
        alert($("#scholarship-short_desc").val());
        $("form").submit();
    });

    $("#scholarship-short_desc").ckeditor();
});
```

I also have the following entries in my html file. I'm using ckeditor 3.6.5.

```
<script src="/myapp/javascripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/myapp/javascripts/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/myapp/javascripts/scholarships/newedit.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This displays the ckeditor correctly in my page. But when I try to set the textarea's value using a val function (as described [here (ckeditor's jquery guide)](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/jQuery_Adapter)), the value is not being set.

Any ideas? thanks! :)

Comment: where does form submit to? Unless you submit via ajax, page is likely being refreshed... browser default submit process

Comment: even if I remove the submit function (which I don't think has anything to do with my question), I get the same issue.

Comment: if `save` is a button in form, `submit` isn't doing anything that browser default isn't already doing...and will cause a page refresh. Look and see if it isn't being refreshed. You have to use ajax to avoid this

Comment: It seems were going offtopic here...
-------------------------------
the alert in the 4th line display nothing even though I set the textarea's value.

Comment: post a link to a live demo that replicates problem

Answer (score 3):

CKEditor doesn't operate on your textarea but on synthetic contenteditable-enabled html page within an iframe. You can set new contents of the editor this way:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.yourInstanceName.setData( '<h1>Your HTML</h1>' );
```

If you really want to synchronize your editor with its textarea:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.yourInstanceName.updateElement();
```

This also happens automatically when you call:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.yourInstanceName.destroy()
```

You'll find `yourInstanceName` by browsing `CKEDITOR.instances` object or by reading textarea's id/name (depends on how you created your editor).

Happy coding! ;)